# Why is the "sub" from "substance" pronounced in a different way than the one from "substantial"?

Tags: pronunciation

Please help me to understand how english works, please!

Comment: I don't think of them as being pronounced differently. You might want to explain in more detail what you mean.

Comment: There's a slight difference in emphasis, but the two are pronounced pretty much the same, in most dialects I'm familiar with.

Answer (score 3):

"Substance" has a primary stressed initial syllable with a caret vowel.  "Substantial" has an unstressed initial syllable with a reduced vowel, a schwa.  Caret vowel is back; schwa is non-back.  The vowel of "sub" in "substantial" can reduce despite being in a closed syllable, because "sub" is a Latinate prefix, so it is like the vowel of "con" in "constrained" in that respect.